# Create grid (n,n) with selected page elements

Tags: google-apps-script, sidebar, add-on, google-slides

Using Google application script, I am generating a grid with selected elements.
In this example below - I gave input rows 2 and columns 3 to generate the order of the grid.
My logic seems to be the production of wrong rows and columns.

**Issue** : number of rows and columns are wrong.

```
function grid() {
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  var pageElements = selection.getPageElementRange().getPageElements();

  //init
  var numRows = 2;
  var horizontalSpace = 5;
  var numColumns = 3;
  var verticalSpace = 10;

  /*get Left, Top, width, height of ist shape.*/
  var shape0Left = pageElements[0].asShape().getLeft(),
    shape0Top = pageElements[0].asShape().getTop(),
    shape0Width = pageElements[0].asShape().getWidth(),
    shape0Height = pageElements[0].asShape().getHeight();

  /*Set the element properties*/
  var elemLeft = shape0Left,
    elemTop = shape0Top,
    elemWidth = 0,
    elemHeight = 0;

  /*Iterate the page selected elements*/
  pageElements.forEach(function(item, index) {
    pageElements[index]
      .asShape()
      .setLeft(elemLeft)
      .setTop(elemTop);

    /*Something wrong with the logic*/
    if ((index + 1) % numRows == 0) {
      /*update the properties of each shape to place in row column order */
      elemTop = shape0Top + pageElements[index].asShape().getHeight() + 10;
      elemLeft = shape0Left;
    } else {
      elemLeft = shape0Left + pageElements[index].asShape().getWidth() + 10;
    }
  });
}
```

Coming Result[image]
Expected output:[image]

Comment: Yah ! you are right. i will take care @TheMaster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the strategy you are taking, you should update the `elemTop` and `elemLeft` variables using the `+=` operator to be sure to include the old value where appropriate.

Also, you've set these nice `verticalSpace` and `horizontalSpace` constants; use them!

If you need to break out of the element loop early because you only want to manipulate the first 6 elements, you cannot use `forEach` on the entire array (at least not without a `if (index >= 6) return;` guard).  You can just loop through with a regular `for` loop and test that `i < rumRows * numColumns`, or you can get just the first *n* elements with `pageElements.slice(0, n)` and use `forEach` on *that* array.

Lastly, the way you have set this up we need to check if we are at the last column or not.  To check the current column number (zero indexed), you can use `var col = i % numColumns`.

With a `for` loop:

```js
  /*Iterate the page selected elements*/
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows * numColumns; ++i) {       
    pageElements[i].asShape().setLeft(elemLeft).setTop(elemTop);
    var col = i % numColumns;
    if ((col+1) % numColumns == 0) {         
      elemTop += pageElements[i].asShape().getHeight() + verticalSpace;
      elemLeft = shape0Left;   
    } else {
      elemLeft += pageElements[i].asShape().getWidth() + horizontalSpace;
    }
  }
```

Using `slice` and `forEach`:

```js
  pageElements.slice(0, numRows * numColumns).forEach(function(item, index){
    item.asShape().setLeft(elemLeft).setTop(elemTop);
    var col = index % numColumns;
    if ((col+1) % numColumns == 0) {         
      elemTop += item.asShape().getHeight() + verticalSpace;
      elemLeft = shape0Left;   
    } else {
      elemLeft += item.asShape().getWidth() + horizontalSpace;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yeh ! It's pretty much working. How you quickly analyzed the problem and solution. I too want learn that way of solving problems. Please guide or let's chat in room. Please

Comment: If you would like to make this script more professional, please share your updated answer. All new SO users will appreciate..